# Generating a unique purchase based on date and qualifier

Tags: vba, date, unique

I am trying to use VBA to produce a purchase order number.  That number is based on the date plus a "-1 or 2 or 3 or 4, etc" to ensure there are no duplicates for multiple purchase orders generated on the same day.  I have gotten to the point where it will generate the PO with "-1" at the end, recognize that PO already exists in my range and product a new PO with a "-2" at the end.  However, I can't get it to produce a PO greater than "-2".  Here is my code:

```
Set ws2 = Worksheets("Data Sheet")
Dim ponum As String
Dim podate As String
Dim n As Integer

ws2.Activate
ActiveSheet.Unprotect "1896"

podate = Format(Now(), "yyyymmdd")

n = 1

ponum = podate & "-" & n

Set Rng = Worksheets("Data Sheet").Range("A1:A100000")
For Each c In Rng.Cells
   If c.Value <> "" And c.Value = ponum Then
   n = n + 1
   ponum = podate & "-" & n
   End If
Next c
```

Comment: You can approach it in couple ways. Do you ever change sort of this list? Maybe just take the last row, check if it's todays date and increment the index? Or use max function on this range? It would require fixed length of your index though, so if you predict more than 9 pos a day, you would need to use yyyymmdd-01 etc.

Comment: I you want to go through all cells anyway, you should rather put all values in array `arr = Worksheets("Data Sheet").Range("A1:A100000").Value`, then iterate over it.

Comment: I am not sure checking the last row would work, the code starts with date-1, if it's the 4th PO of the day, the formula would only be looking for a -1, not a -3.

Comment: I meant checking the last row of data. If it's sorted oldest to newest, last row will have the latest PO id. Then you can check if the date matches today. It's far from perfect, but may be good enough.